# Variables in a do while loop

Tags: java, do-while

Below is some code asking the user to input an integer.

```
public int getValidInput() {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer >=1 and <=10: ");
        int number = user_input.nextInt();

    } while (number > 10 || number < 0);

    return number;
}
```

The code as shown does not work although when I initialise number outside the do command i.e. set it to int number; and then in the do loop set `number = user_input.nextInt();` it does. Why does it work in one case and not the other?

Comment: Because of the scope of the `variable` defined. Since it is defined inside `do` statement it will not be available for `while`

Comment: This does not even compile?!

Comment: `number > 10 && number < 0` will never yield true, use `||` instead.

Comment: While the answers are correct, they don't question why the language designers chose not to include the while condition in the scope of the while loop. Just because it is lexically outside it, in that it appears after the closing brace, it doesn't necessarily mean that it should be logically outside. In fact, it seems intuitive to me that everything up to the semicolon at the end of the while line should be part of the scope of the whole do-while loop. This would make it consistent with the locally declared variable in a for loop, which is still visible inside the body of the for loop.

Answer (score 8):

Because in Java, variables are scoped to the block in which they're declared. In your example, the `int number =` is *within* the `do...while` block, and so the variable only exists within that block.

By moving the declaration out of the block, into the block for the method, the variable exists for the method's entire block (including nested blocks).

Comment: @TJ's day has begun.. :) Whenever I come to UK, if I get a change, I wanna meet you once.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao you can directly comment the suggestions here. ;)

Comment: Well.. Time is the answer.. :D

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have defined `number` inside your loop. Variables are scoped in Java, so variables declared inside loops or if statements are not accessible outside those loops or if statements. You can fix your code, simply by moving the declaration, as shown below:

```
public int getValidInput() {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer >=1 and <=10: ");
        number = user_input.nextInt();
    } while (number>10 || number < 0);

    return number;
}
```

Comment: Update while condition with ||

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces `{}` of the do-while open up a so called scope (they always do, wether in methods or loops or ifs). Any declaration inside a scope is only visible while you are within that scope, and also in any inner scope opened within the scope.

The condition of your `while` is *outside* the curly braces, so it does not see any variable declared *within* them. If you put the `int number;` before the `do`, it's on the same scope level like the `while` condition, so it, along with the value it gained inside the loop, is visible to the expressions in the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions are used to enter a body from outside that body, so the variable which decides the truth value of condition has to exist before the body.
And as the body block of do-while loop is the code to be executed, therefore the code which decides to execute it must be other than itself.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable restricted to `{}`. outside of that braces you cannot access. When you initialised it on top it access across both do and while as the scope is increased.